# Avoid duplication when serializing/deserializing mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb, rust, serde

I have 2 collections:

- profiles
- dances

```
struct Profile {
   id: String,
   firstname: String,
   dances: Vec<String>
}

struct DanceModel {
   id: String,
   name: String,
}
```

I have a find query which does a lookup on the dances collection.

```
let cursor = profile_collection.aggregate(pipeline, None).await.unwrap();
let results = cursor.try_collect().await.unwrap_or_else(|_| vec![]);
let profile = results.first().unwrap();        
let result = bson::from_document::<ProfileResult>(profile.clone());
```

I created a new model like so:

```
struct ProfileResult {
   id: String,
   name: String,
   dances: Vec<DanceModel>
}
```

As you can see, the id and name fields are being duplicated, and I have 2 models for the same data.

Is there any way to avoid duplication of attributes and data models?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code lacks a `main`, `use` statements and the definition of the `profile_collection` variable.
You have to understand that your chances to get an answer are a lot higher if people can just copy your code and play with it. Having to add all of those things will make people shy away from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to apply an object concept to a procedural technology.

To work around this issue, you can create an IdName struct and apply that struct to the model in a uid field.

```
struct IdName {
   id: String,
   name: String,
}

struct Profile {
   id: String,
   firstname: String,
   dances: Vec<String>
}

struct DanceModel {
   uid: IdName
}

struct ProfileResult {
    uid: IdName
    dances: Vec<DanceModel>
}
```